# Mock that have all method return value set to same value

Tags: python, mocking

I have a class that takes `argparse` args with many options:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args

    def something(self):
        if self.args.option1:
            ...
        ...


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--option1", action="store_true")
p.add_argument("--option2", action="store_true")
...
args = p.parse_args()

a = A(args)
a.something()
```

Now I want to test that

```
def test_something():
    a = A(...) # What to put here?
```

It would be nice if I could have `Mock` that returns `False` for every option. I could write

```
def test_something():
    m = Mock()
    for attr in ["option1", "option2"]:
        setattr(m, attr, lambda: False)

    a = A(m)
    ...
```

But there can be dozens of options and I am pretty sure it should be possible to do that in some elegant way without listing them.

How to achieve my goal without listing all parser options again?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a mock. You can either call `p.parse_args` with an explicit list of arguments, or you can construct an appropriate `Namespace` instance manually.

```
def test_something():
    # If you have access to p
    args = p.parse_args([])  # produces Namespace(option1=False, option2=False)
    a = A(args)
```

or

```
from argparse import Namespace


def test_something():
    args = Namespace(option1=False, option2=False)
    a = A(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

During writing the question such solution came to my mind:

```
class FalseMock(Mock):
    def __getattr__(self, name: str):
        return lambda: False
```

But doesn't seem elegant enough for me, maybe some of you have different ideas?